# Node JS driver.findElements(by.className('classname').getText() throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am trying to get a feedback from Selenium tests and closest I've come to solution was with:

`driver.findElement(By.className('classname')).getText();`

But to make it effective I have to find all Elements with same classname, so I tried changing it to:

```
driver.findElements(By.className('classname')).getText();
```

but I get an error:

> *TypeError: driver.findElements(...).getText is not a function*

Any suggestions how to fix it or ideas for code with equivalent function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.findElements()` returns a collection and `.getText()` doesn't work on a collection, only a single element. If you want the text from each element, you will need to loop through the collection and get text on each element inside the loop.

See [this reference](http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/) if you need more info on looping through a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since `findElements` returns a collection, you can use the `map` method to loop through the collection and get the text for all the elements.

```
let array_of_elements = driver.findElements(By.className('some_classname'));

//get the text from the elements in an another array

let text_of_elements = array_of_elements.map((array_of_text,index,array_of_elements)=>{
   return array_of_text.getText();
});
```

Read about the map method [here](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-5df1c7eee464).

Answer (score -1):

You can get Text Collection Using:

```
List<WebElement> findData = driver.findElements("******");
for (WebElement webElement : findData) {
                    String getValueofString = webElement.getText();                 
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with JS. This code with java is not helpful to the OP.